# wxPython: Highlight item in GidSizer upon mouse click

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a Panel with a bunch of pictures placed on it in a GridSizer layout. How can I draw a highlighted color around the edge of an image or its border to show that it has been selected upon a mouse click event?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Widget Inspection Tool's code. It can highlight any widget. On my machine, it's in the "_InspectionHighlighter" class in the inspection.py file, which is here: C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\lib

You can read about the tool here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool

Answer (score 0):

You could put each picture in a panel, and use `SetBackgroundColour()`to set the background color of the panel.